# angular animation new element from input to destination

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

I've got a problem with one animation in angular. I want to make newly created element to 'travel' from input where it was created to destination.

I think it is connected with changing css `position` attribute while animation from absolute to relative, but don't know why it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

part of index.html:

```
<form ng-submit="add(name)">
  <input type="text" id="input-element" class="form-control" ng-model="name" />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
</form>
<ul>
  <li class="animation" ng-repeat="item in list"><b>{{item}}</b></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.animation.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  -o-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  transition: 0.5s linear all;
}

.animation.ng-enter {
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

controller's body (not connected with my problem):

```
$scope.list = [];
$scope.add = function(name) {
  $scope.list.push(name);
};
```

When I remove `position: relative` from `.animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active`, it is always as absolute. When I leave it, position is always relative.

How to make such 'travel' animation from input to destination with angular-animate?

Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/m1xoP6GpJJZzhFhjALRd?p=preview.

Comment: Would probably be easier to implement with JS.

Comment: Right, but maybe someone knows better solution.